# How to handle memory in aws cpp sdk?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently have worked on aws-cpp-sdk from AWS service.
But unfortunately I couldn't understand how to handle memory because there aren't enough tutorials or examples on the internet.

**What I have tried are as follows.**
1. built aws-cpp-sdk as a 64bit shared dll for windows x64(exactly win10, vs 2015) using CMake.
2. And used that library in win32 console application to test.
3. But it's complicated while using their SDK.
**First attached my code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <aws\s3\S3Client.h>
#include <aws\core\Aws.h>
#include <aws\s3\model\PutObjectRequest.h>

using namespace Aws;
using namespace Aws::S3;
using namespace Aws::S3::Model;

static const char* ALLOCATION_TAG = "memory";
static const char* S3_BUCKET_NAME = "XXXXXXXX";
static const char* S3_KEY = "Hello";

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions  options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    Client::ClientConfiguration config;
    auto mS3Client = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3Client>(ALLOCATION_TAG, config);
    auto requestStream = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("s3-sample");
    *requestStream << "Hello World!";
    Model::PutObjectRequest request;
    request.WithKey(S3_KEY).WithBucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME);
    request.SetBody(requestStream);
    auto outcome = mS3Client->PutObject(request);
    bool bRet = false;
    if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        bRet = true;
        std::cout << "Put object succeeded" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        bRet = false;
        std::cout << "Error while putting Object " << outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() <<
            " " << outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass PutObjectRequest **request** to PutObject function, the variabes of the request are not passed exactly.
In detail, bucket name I put "XXXXXXX" is not available(empty string) in PutObject function in S3Client.cpp file.
Attached PutObject function.

```
PutObjectOutcome S3Client::PutObject(const PutObjectRequest& request) const
{
  Aws::StringStream ss;
  ss << m_uri << "/";
  ss << request.GetBucket(); //here exception occured because request.GetBucket() returns empty string.
  ss << "/";
  ss << request.GetKey();
  XmlOutcome outcome = MakeRequest(ss.str(), request, HttpMethod::HTTP_PUT);
  if(outcome.IsSuccess())
  {
    return PutObjectOutcome(PutObjectResult(outcome.GetResult()));
  }
  else
  {
    return PutObjectOutcome(outcome.GetError());
  }
}
```

I am not sure why the value of Bucket Name isn't passed correctly(maybe it's a memory related problem, i think).
Please help me what and how I should handle memory allocation in this code.
Hope the great solutions.
PS: Any links to detailed tutorial would be okay.(Anyway I can't find through googling. :-( )

Comment: I finally solved this issue this way. I was add dependencies of aws sdk manually in project settings. And I followed their instruction to create start-up project automatically. Refer to his blog: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-cmake-exports-with-the-aws-sdk-for-c/)
Use automated script they make or exactly set all properties in Project settings manually. Hope this helpful.